# Authorization process on FTP server

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, controls

I am writing FTP server.
My problem is how to control user access on file or directory.

Is there any algorithm for user access determination?
The following case bother me in these days:
For example,

I have a access control entry, 
it states that user A can read root directory "/",
However, there are no access control entry to grant read access to user A to read "/abc" directory.

How can I determine whether user A can read the directory "/abc"?

Another example,
I have a access control entry, 
it states that user A can write file on root directory "/",
However, there are no access control entry to grant write access to user A to write file to "/abc" directory.
How can I determine whether user A can write file the directory "/abc"?

Should I create an access control entry for each object in the file system?
I have no experience on this issue,so my question may be not clear.

Comment: It is really depends on what language your using, your tags are a bit confusing. But I'm not an expert and maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: You can use permission inheritance: unless /a/b/c explicitly sets a particular permission, the permission for /a/b is checked, and so on.